# Need Assististance with converting jquery single function to object instances with multiple functions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hello:  I have a lists of teams stored in a database and they are all associated with a division.  each team has a "div_id" and a "team_id".  I have a jquery function (dropdown) that is fed the div_id and then does an ajax call to look up the teams for that division and list them in another dropdown...

this all worked; so what I am trying to do now is essentially have multiple instances of this on a page.  And all of them being independent of each other.  so I figured that for these to independent of each other; they will need to be objects.  I have done objects in PHP but never JS.  In PHP I always stored the objects in an array so I figured the same thing here.  So I made an attempt to convert my working single solution to a solution that will work several times on a page.  It did not work so I am looking for some help.  I will first post the "working" single version.  And then I will post the attempt I made to convert it into objects...

Here is function that worked with single set of dropdowns:

```
$gym_id=$_POST['gym_id'];
?>

<style>
#slot_cont1 {width: 100%; height: 50px; border: 1px solid red;}
</style>

<form action="/wp-admin/gc_admin_partial_complete_games.php" method="post" id="submit1" name="submit1" >

<input type="hidden" name="gc_post" value=3>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM scheduler_slots WHERE gym_id=$gym_id AND status='open' LIMIT 0,3";
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)     {//gxx1

?>
<div id="slot_cont1">
<?php

$slot_date=$row[slot_date];
$slot_start=$row[slot_start];

$slot_id=$row[gc_id];

$div_box_id="ajax_content-".$slot_id;
$function_name="G_function1-".$slot_id;

echo $slot_date." - ".$slot_start;
?>

<style>

#ajax_content {width: 175px; margin: 15px 0 15px 0; }

#ajax_content a {color: #394f68; text-decoration: underline;}
#ajax_content a:hover {color: black;}
#upper_container {width: 100%;}
</style>

<select id="comboA" name="<?php echo $function_name; ?>"    onchange="G_function1(this)">
<option value=""></option>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM scheduler_divisions ORDER BY gc_order";
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $resultsg1)
{

 $div_id = $resultsg1[div_id];
 $div_name = $resultsg1[div_name];

 ?>

  <option value="<?php echo $div_id; ?>"  >

  <?php echo $div_name; ?></option>

<?php   } ?>

</select>

<div id="<?php echo $div_box_id; ?>" id="id57512">
</div>
<hr>
</div>
<?php

}// close gxx1

?>

<br style="clear: both;"/>
<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />

</form>

<script>

 function G_function1(sel) {
 var value = sel.value;  
 var answer = value;
$.ajax({
 cache: false,
 type: 'GET',
 url:  'http://scheduler.mydomain.com/gscript6_team_dropdown.php',
 data: 'answer=' + answer,
 dataType: 'html',
 success: function(response) {
    $("#<?php echo $div_box_id; ?>").html(response);
  }
});

    }
</script>


<script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Ok so now here is my attempt to convert it:

```
$gym_id=$_POST['gym_id'];
?>
<style>
#slot_cont1 {width: 100%; height: 50px; border: 1px solid red;}
</style>

<form action="/wp-admin/gc_admin_partial_complete_games.php" method="post" id="submit1" name="submit1" >

<input type="hidden" name="gc_post" value=3>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM scheduler_slots WHERE gym_id=$gym_id AND status='open' LIMIT 0,3";
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)     {//gxx1

?>
<div id="slot_cont1">
<?php

$slot_date=$row[slot_date];
$slot_start=$row[slot_start];

$slot_id=$row[gc_id];

?>
<script>
var jsslot='<?php echo $slot_id; ?>';
</script>
<?php

$div_box_id="ajax_content-".$slot_id;
$function_name="G_function1-".$slot_id;


echo $slot_date." - ".$slot_start;
?>

<style>

#ajax_content {width: 175px; margin: 15px 0 15px 0; }

#ajax_content a {color: #394f68; text-decoration: underline;}
#ajax_content a:hover {color: black;}
#upper_container {width: 100%;}
</style>

<select id="comboA" name="<?php echo $function_name; ?>"  onchange="person(this)">
<option value=""></option>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM scheduler_divisions ORDER BY gc_order";
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $resultsg1)
{

 $div_id = $resultsg1[div_id];
 $div_name = $resultsg1[div_name];

 ?>

 <option value="<?php echo $div_id; ?>"  >

 <?php echo $div_name; ?></option>

 <?php   } ?>

</select>

<div id="<?php echo $div_box_id; ?>" id="id57512">
</div>
<hr>
</div>
<?php

}// close gxx1

?>

<br style="clear: both;"/>
<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />

</form>

<script>

function person(div_id,slot_id) {
this.div_id = div_id;
this.slot_id = slot_id;

this.show_teams = function (div_id,slot_id) {
    var value = div_id.value;  
 var answer = value;
$.ajax({
cache: false,
type: 'GET',
url:  'http://scheduler.mydomain.com/gscript6_team_dropdown.php',
data: 'answer=' + answer,
dataType: 'html',
success: function(response) {
    $("#<?php echo $div_box_id; ?>").html(response);
}
});
}
}
var show_them[slot_id] = new person(div_id,slot_id);

 show_them.show_teams(div_id,slot_id);

    }
</script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

so the second version is not working so I am hoping someone can help me with it...

******************** update 2:42am EST ***********************
OK Roamer:  here is my new code based on your answer:

```
$gym_id=$_POST['gym_id'];

?>

<style>
#slot_cont1 {width: 100%; height: 50px; border: 1px solid red;}
</style>

<form action="/wp-admin/gc_admin_partial_complete_games.php" method="post" id="submit1" name="submit1" >

<input type="hidden" name="gc_post" value=3>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM scheduler_slots WHERE gym_id=$gym_id AND status='open' LIMIT 0,3";
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)     {//gxx1

?>
<div id="slot_cont1">
<?php

$slot_date=$row[slot_date];
$slot_start=$row[slot_start];

$slot_id=$row[gc_id];

?>
<script>
var jsslot='<?php echo $slot_id; ?>';
</script>
<?php

$div_box_id="ajax_content-".$slot_id;
$function_name="G_function1-".$slot_id;


echo $slot_date." - ".$slot_start;
?>

<style>
#ajax_content {width: 175px; margin: 15px 0 15px 0; }
#ajax_content a {color: #394f68; text-decoration: underline;}
#ajax_content a:hover {color: black;}
#upper_container {width: 100%;}
</style>

<select class="divisions" name="<?php echo $function_name; ?>">
<option value=""></option>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM scheduler_divisions ORDER BY gc_order";
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $resultsg1)
{

 $div_id = $resultsg1[div_id];
 $div_name = $resultsg1[div_name];

 ?>

 <option value="<?php echo $div_id; ?>"  >

<?php echo $div_name; ?></option>

<?php   } ?>

</select>

<div class="teams"></div>

<hr>
</div>
<?php

}// close gxx1

?>

<br style="clear: both;"/>
<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />

</form>

<script>

$(function() {
$("select.divisions").on('change', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET',
        url:   'http://scheduler.mydomain.com/gscript6_team_dropdown.php',
        data: 'answer=' + $this.val(),
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(response) {
            //find the appropriate teams div relative to `this` select element and stuff the response into it.
            $this.nextAll(".teams").html(response);
        }
    });
});
});

</script>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

So that is my new code base on R's answer but still do nothing.  So if anyone can help with this it will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: What does it mean "is not working"? What does it, what you expect, what errors did you get etc.?

Comment: Hello Dawid:  what I mean is when you select items on the dropdown nothing happens...(supposed to be a dropdown of teams that appears)...

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to need to do much to fix this :

- In the HTML, use classes, not ids, to identify the select elements and their target divs.
- Make sure the scripts and link tag are in the document's `<head>...</head>`
- Attach the onchange handler in javascript, not HTML.
- In the onchange handler, traverse the DOM to find the appropriate teams div *relative* to the select element whose change event is being handled.
- Wrap the script in `$(function() {...});` to ensure it doesn't attempt to run until the DOM's `ready` event fires

**HTML**

```
<select class="divisions" name="<?php echo $function_name; ?>">...</select>
<div class="teams"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $("select.divisions").on('change', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            url:  'http://scheduler.mydomain.com/gscript6_team_dropdown.php',
            data: 'answer=' + $this.val(),
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(response) {
                //find the appropriate teams div relative to `this` select element and stuff the response into it.
                $this.nextAll(".teams").html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello Roamer:  thanks for your answer - i tried to apply it but it did not work (does nothing when you select a division), I will add my code to the end of my question above

Comment: Hello Roamer:  after looking at this again, I see that i did not follow all of your directions, so need to rework this a little, I will be gone for several hours but will let you know when i can get back to this (and I do not know anything about "js error console"; I am just running it on a webpage...

Comment: @gman_donster, if you want to develop apps involving javascript you must know how to access your browser's Console. It displays error messages and debugging messages of your choice. For details, look in your browser's Help.